# Написать функцию сколько осталось секунд до завтра

Tags: javascript

```js
function getSecondsToTomorrow(){
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getHours() * 3600 + d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getSeconds();
  d.setHours(23, 59, 59, 59);
  var v = d.getHours() * 3600 + d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getSeconds();
   var e = v  - s;
   return e;
}
console.log(getSecondsToTomorrow())
```

Я написал такую функцию скажите правильно ?

Comment: она выдает правильные значения?

Comment: @Grundy не знаю

Comment: Эм... В сутках 86400 секунды. Если взять текущее время и преобразовать в секунды, то получим сколько всего секунд уже ушло. Отнимаем наши секунды от 86400 и вуаля!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно всё это можно значительно укоротить, чтобы одно подразумевало другое, но я просто хотел всё разложить по полочкам.

```js
// Вначале берём сам Date
var obDate = new Date();
// Собирём всё в массив чтоб легко представить в нужое
var currDate = [];
// Текущий год
var Year = currDate.push(obDate.getFullYear());
// Текущий месяц
var Month = currDate.push(obDate.getMonth() + 1);
// Текущий день
var date = currDate.push(obDate.getDate());
// Выводим в строку итог стандатрного формата yyyy-m-d H:i:s
var ending = currDate.join('-') + ' 03:07:59'; // Мой день закончится в 02:32:59
// вычисляем разницу от текущего времени ( Math чтоб глаза не болели)) )
var diff = Math.round((new Date(ending).getTime() / 1000) - (obDate.getTime() / 1000));
// смотрим
if (diff > 0) {
  console.log('Время осталось: ' + diff + ' сек.');
} else {
  console.log('Время вышло на.. )) ');
};
```

Comment: На момент публикации мой время менялось))  03:07:59

Answer (score 2):

Да, ваша функция работает верно.

Для проверки вы можете взять значение секунд, которое вам возвращает функция. Добавить его к текущему времени и проверить полученный результат - должно быть *текущая дата 23:59:59*:

```
var d = new Date();
var left = getSecondsToTomorrow
d.setTime((new Date()).getTime() + getSecondsToTomorrow() * 1000);
console.log(d.toString());
```

Мой вариант getSecondsToTomorrow():

```
function getSecondsToTomorrow() {
    var now = Date.now(), // текущее время(UNIX timestamp) в миллисек.
    period = 86400 * 1000; //сутки в миллисек.
    return Math.floor((Math.floor((now + period)/period) * period - now) / 1000) + (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60; // кол-во секунд до следующих суток
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Идея в том, чтобы получить разницу в милисекундах из текущего дня и завтрашнего, а потом производить вычисления даты.

```js
const myFunc = () => {
  var dateNow = new Date();
  
  var tomorrow = new Date(dateNow.getFullYear(), dateNow.getMonth(), dateNow.getDate() + 1);
  
  var getSeconds = tomorrow - dateNow;
  var seconds = getSeconds / 1000;
  var minutes = seconds / 60;
  var hours = minutes / 60;
  
  console.log("Секунд: " + Math.round(seconds));
  console.log("Минут: " + Math.round(minutes));
  console.log("Часов: " + Math.round(hours));
};

myFunc();
```